# Replace multiple occurance of the word in the line of the file using perl

Tags: perl

Need to replace multiple occurrence of the words in the lines of the text file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my $string2 = 'first_part';

my $string3 = 'middle_part';

my $string4 = 'last_part';

my @contents=();

tie @contents, 'Tie::File','test.html' or die "Not able to Tie test.html\n";

my $count=1;

foreach (@contents)

{

my $string = $_;

my $quoted_substring = quotemeta($string);

my $before = 'test_example_start';

my $after  = 'text_example_end';

if ($string =~ /\Q$before\E(.*?)\Q$after\E/) {

my $finalstr = "$string2$1$string3$1$string4"; 

s/$quoted_substring/$finalstr/g;


 print $finalstr;  

} 
        $count++;

    my $finalstr ='';

}

untie @contents;
```

Actual string:

```
test_example_start this is lesson-1 text_example_end where everyone attended the class test_example_start this is lesson-2 text_example_end where two members attended the class test_example_start this is lesson-3 text_example_end where five members attended the class
```

---

expected result:

```
first_part this is lesson-1 middle_part this is lesson-1 last_part where everyone attended the class first_part this is lesson-2 middle_part this is lesson-1 last_part where two members attended the class first_part this is lesson-1 middle_part this is lesson-3 last_part where five members attended the class
```

---

current result:
whole paragraph is replaced with only one line. as below

```
first_part this is lesson-1 middle_part this is lesson-1 last_part
```

Comment: Could you please properly format your post? (see [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems a bit confusing. The requirements are not very clear, despite the fact that you provided "actual string" and "expected result".

This code should provide something very close to what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open FILE, "<", "test.html" or die $!;

while (my $fileline = <FILE>) {
    while ($fileline =~ m/test_example_start(.*?)text_example_end(.*?)((?=test_example_start)|($))/gi) {
        print "first_part$1middle_part$1last_part$2";
    }
    print "\n";
}

close FILE;
```

Assuming that the contents of the file `test.html` are the following:

> test_example_start this is lesson-1 text_example_end where everyone attended the class test_example_start this is lesson-2 text_example_end where two members attended the class test_example_start this is lesson-3 text_example_end where five members attended the class

then, the above script's output will be:

> first_part this is lesson-1 middle_part this is lesson-1 last_part where everyone attended the class first_part this is lesson-2 middle_part this is lesson-2 last_partwhere two members attended the class first_part this is lesson-3 middle_part this is lesson-3 last_part where five members attended the class

I'm not sure if this is what you want, because I don't know what exactly you want to be inserted in the newly created `middle_part`

Aside from a correction in your regex, and the code cleanup, the key point here is that, if you want all of a line's ocurrences to be replaced, then you should put the line test inside a `while` block, not an `if`.